# Backbone validation and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

can anyone help me, Javascript taking the function 'detect' as undefined , how can we return value from callback to detect function ?

```
validate: function (attrs, options) {
    if (!this.detect(attrs.selectedFile, this.onComplete)) {
        return "this is an error message";
    }
},

detect: function (file, callback) {
    var attributes = this.attributes,
        image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        if (condition_is_false_return_false) {
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true);
        }
    };
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
},

onComplete: function (value) {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `this.detact` should be `this.detect`.

Comment: this is not the solution. typo occur when posting the question on stackoverflow but not in the code

Comment: _typo occur when posting the question_ Does it mean you've typed this code manually when posting the question? Why not just copy-paste it from your source (if it has no typos)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code. 
1. The validate function only validate the attr candidate, the "this" object here is ambiguous, it may not be the model. therefore this.detect is undefined. You may have to use bind function in underscore.

2. The validate function technically runs before the attributes are set. So even if you can successfully call the detect function, inside it, when you do this.attributes, you will get an empty set. So you can't detect anything. It is better to try to make these functions static, meaning they don't refer to "this"

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickrechard/omnfbtud/21/),

```
    var myOwnModel=Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize:function(model,options){
    Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
    },
    validate: function (attrs, options) {
        console.log("doing validate",attrs);
    if (!this.detect(attrs.selectedFile, this.onComplete)) {
        return "this is an error message";
    }
    },

    detect: function (file, callback) {
        var attributes = this.attributes,

            image = new Image();
                    console.log("running detect",attributes) // Here attributes does not have the new attr. 
        image.onload = function () {
            if (condition_is_false_return_false) {
                callback(false);
            } else {
                callback(true);
            }
        };
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    },

    onComplete: function (value) {
        return value;
    }

})

var a=new myOwnModel({a:1})
a.fetch();
// or test it with 
a.set({b:1},{validate:true});
console.log(a)
```

looks like the validate does have access to "this". And detect function is successfully running. So what was the problem?

Comment: problem is that, image.onload giving me the width and height and on this basis i am returning 'true' or 'false' but image.onload is async method while my validate function has been run earlier. Actually i want to validate image dimensions in validate function.